# IOS: iAD advertising

Tags: ios, iad, ads

In my app I insert advertising with the iAd framework and it work fine. But now I want to know how to set advertising inside these banners.
Is there some services where I should register my application? Or is it all automatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do agree the iAd Network contract in iTunes Connect and fill the tax forms and your account info, also you need to enable iAd via iTunes Connect.

> **How do I join the iAd Network?**
>
> You must be enrolled in the iOS Developer Program to join the iAd
>   Network. Members need to do the following in iTunes Connect:
>
> ```
> - Agree to the iAd Network Contract.
> - Complete the required tax forms and, if you have not already done so, set up your banking information.
> - Enable your app for iAd rich media ads in the Manage Your Applications module.
> ```

Refer : [iAd](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/iad-network.html) and [iAd Integration](http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=708)

Comment: but after these steps? Apple decide what advertising show in the iad banner?

Comment: @blackguardian: yes, apple will decide according to your primary target groups

Comment: a last question (after I'll accept your answer), tha famous game "Ruzzle" have also some view full screen for advertising (that show when you finish the match), what kind of advertising is that?

Comment: @blackguardian: for fullscreen ad there is a class called ` ADInterstitialAd`, but this is only available for iPad [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html).